# Hacking RadioInfo.java to work

Tags: java, android

I have been looking at the android source and developing some apps. However for my next app, I need information about the cell phone. Similar to what you see when you go into "Field Test" mode. However I have not been successful to get RadioInfo.java to work. Is there a way to hack RadioInfo.java so that I can use it in my app OR is there a way to get the data that is displayed in "Field Test" Mode. I have looked at the telephony api include the telephony.internal but so far they do not provide as much grained information as I would want.
I have been asking around on the net but so far I can't find this information.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get very far I am afraid as the underlying file is attempting to interact with the baseband chip through an internal api that you   will not get access to for an application.

Comment: Well since it is open source I could get access to the API by downloading the source code and looking through it and making changes and then building and loading it onto the phone. That is the vision I have but once again that is a round about way I would like to avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: You still do not get it not every api is accessible via the Androis application java interface..telephony parts is one those areas.